# Cannot log into RealVNC server running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, realvnc

I successfully installed RealVNC Server on 2 instances of Ubuntu. Authorized and started. I then ran RealVNC Viewer from Windows, and was asked for username and password.

Tried logging in using my regular login account on the host, but it failed to authenticate. Tried using username@localhost (both by name and IP), even tried using the username of the Windows client.

It's not clear what username it is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication mechanism depends on the version of VNC Server that you are using. From [Authenticating connections to VNC Server](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/aj1074738.html):

By default, users must authenticate in order to connect
to *VNC Server*. Note this is *not* the same as logging on to the host computer (though the same credentials may be used for both).

By default:

• *VNC Server (Enterprise)* 
and *VNC Server (Personal)* specify system
authentication. This means that a user must supply the credentials of
a host computer user in order to connect. See [Authenticating using host computer
user credentials](http://a%20%20href=%22https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/aj1074738.html#Raj32417).

• *VNC Server (Free)* specifies VNC authentication. This means that a user must supply a password specific to VNC in order to connect. See [Authenticating using a VNC password](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/aj1074738.html#Raj84193).

Comment: Yes, read that from their documentation. Using Enterprise version.. states that 'user must supply the credentials of a host (assuming they mean the computer where VNCServer is running) computer user', which is what I am doing, but won't let me login. I can open a telnet session with the same credentials successfully.

Comment: The documentation does show a way of adding users, but using the GUI on the Linux machine. I am accessing and configuring VNC via remote terminal sessions only. The physical machines are half way round the planet.